# TypeError: browser.webRequest is undefined

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to log errors using webextension. I have the follwoing simple example to start with:

`manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testOnErrorWebex",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Adds a red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["testOnErrorWebex.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
  "webRequest"
]

}
```

And, the content script: `testOnErrorWebex.js`

```
console.log("-- inside js file --");

var target = "<all_urls>"; 

/*
e.g., with no network:
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/"
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESOLVED in Firefox
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED in Chrome
*/

function logError(responseDetails) {
  console.log("-- inside logError  --");
  console.log("inside logError");
  console.log(responseDetails.url);
  console.log(responseDetails.error);
}

browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
  logError,
  {urls: [target]}
);
```

When I try the extension and load it, then type any bad URL that fires an error:
e.g., `https://doesnotexist/`

The following line from the content script is printed:

```
-- inside js file --
```

But I get this eerro:

```
TypeError: browser.webRequest is undefined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `browser.webRequest` is not available in the content scripts.
Please try to change the `testOnErrorWebex.js` to run in background as you can find in the following changed manifest:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testOnErrorWebex",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds a red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["testOnErrorWebex.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is what I got: `The webRequest.addListener filter doesn't overlap with host permissions`.

Comment: It works without a problen in FF 53.0.3 on Ubuntu. Are you trying something different from the code that you posted or only you log the responses?

Comment: Not at all. I copied your post. I'm working on Nightly 54.

Comment: This may be a problem, is a specific reason why you are using a nightly build? Also, the only similar result to your problem found in the wild is [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1367478), which may do not occur in a stable version.

Comment: I will need to use embedded webextension & this require me to use nightly to run it. Because when I try to run SDK from firefox 53, I get an error saying that there is no valid manifest file. Any other suggestions? The above example works in normal FF but not Nightly.

Comment: Web extensions now work for regular versions too

Comment: Sorry, I meant the main extension is SDK and the embedded one is webextension. That's why I need Nightly to run the SDK using jpm. Unless SDK can run in normal FF? I am not aware of that?